# How to deserialize the JSON object in c#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a following JSON code,

```
{
    "dataContainer":{
    "sheets":{
        "1":{
            "0":{
                "1":{
                    "type":6,
                    "value":2,
                    "value2":"11-15-1991"
                },
                "2":{
                    "type":10,
                    "value":3,
                    "value2":3
                }
            },
            "1":{
                "1":{
                    "type":6,
                    "value":7,
                    "value2":"11-16-1991"
                },
                "2":{
                    "type":10,
                    "value":8,
                    "value2":8
                }
            }
        },
        "2":{
            "0":{
                "1":{
                    "type":6,
                    "value":2,
                    "value2":"11-15-1991"
                },
                "2":{
                    "type":10,
                    "value":3,
                    "value2":3
                }
            },
            "1":{
                "1":{
                    "type":6,
                    "value":7,
                    "value2":"11-16-1991"
                },
                "2":{
                    "type":10,
                    "value":8,
                    "value2":8
                }
            }
        }
    }}
}
```

i need to deserialize that code, i have tried that one,

```
Dictionary<string,object> dict = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(obj);
List<object> sheetObject = new List<object>();
sheetObject = ((Dictionary<string, object>)dict["dataContainer"]).Values.ToList();
public object sheets = new object();
sheets = sheetObject[0];
```

but this is not working i want to able to work like below,

```
sheets[1][0][1].type
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: Does not pass validation.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com

Comment: Also what you want is not possible given this structure.

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm deserialize the object in nested dictionary

Answer (score 0):

[Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) is the library to use. This library has a function which will take a JSON string and return a "dynamic" variable representing the JSON.
Syntax goes like this:

```
dynamic dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(YOUR_JSON_STRING);
```

You can now access the entire JSON tree dynamically, e.g.:

```
dynamic sheetObject = dict.dataContainer.sheets;
```

To iterate over the children at any given level, just use a foreach:

```
foreach (dynamic child in sheetObject.Children()) { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: Thanks dude but if there is any possible without using Json.NET.. can you please solve it